# Where do I find API key and API secret for Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, api, keyboard, api-key

Trying to connect to Facebook to make a statusupdate through my Android application.
Got the whole thing running but I need API key + secret. Where can I create/get a hold of these?

```
private static final String apiKey = "<YOUR API KEY>";
private static final String apiSecret = "<YOUR SECRET KEY>";
```

Tried the same thing with Twitter and then I just "created" an application and recieved "ConsumerKEY" and "ConsumerSECRET", but what is the deal with Facebook?

Comment: To know how to get an API key You can refer to the post [http://www.mytechshout.com/how-to-get-facebook-api-key.html](http://www.mytechshout.com/how-to-get-facebook-api-key.html)

Comment: I just followed the instructions above and facebook requires you to register first on the developer site, which requires a verification via mobile phone.  The code sent is 8 characters, but the form field on the code entry page limits entry to 6 characters.  I modified the form with firebug resubmitted.  I'm sure it will be fixed by the time anyone reads this :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to log on to facebook (with any valid account), go to Account -> Application settings -> Developer -> Set up new application (button at the top right). After creating application you will see the key and secret at application settings page.

Answer (score 6):

Nowaday, facebook developers page and creating API process was changed.
now you must to open [developers.facebook.com/apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) . If you have registrated as a facebook developer you will see in top of the right **create new app**, otherwise you have to  do **registration**. After than create a app. I use the site as a [helper](http://ftutorials.com/facebook-api-key/) and [the url](http://25labs.com/tutorial-integrate-facebook-connect-to-your-website-using-php-sdk-v-3-x-x-which-uses-graph-api/) helpful too, but the site is a few older.

[Here is docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/) you can get all information about creating new app.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create an application at http://www.facebook.com/developers/. This will give you an API key and secret specific to your app.

Comment: But this looks like it's for a website and not a application running on Android phones? They as me to type in a website and then presents a file for me to download and upload to my website?

Comment: You don't need to use it on a website. The same key and secret can be used for a Facebook Connect website or an app. The wizards are set up for quick-start for people wanting to add a few things to their existing site. If you want to bypass the wizards, http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php is available.